# Is it possible to update a SOPS-encrypted file without decrypting it first?

Tags: security, encryption, terraform, mozilla-sops

I'm using Mozilla SOPS to encrypt secrets, the results of which are committed to a git repo shared by the other members of a project. When using SOPS for personal projects, I am using `age` to encrypt/decrypt the contents of my SOPS files; if I have a file called `my-secrets.sops.yaml` and I want to add a new key/value pair to it, my normal workflow is:

1. Run `sops -d -i my-secrets.sops.yaml` to decrypt the file in-place so that the values are plaintext.
2. Add `new_secret: "ThisIsASecret"` to the file.
3. Run `sops -e -i my-secrets.sops.yaml` to encrypt the file in-place.
4. Commit the changes to git.

This works for my personal projects because I generate the `age` secret and public keys myself, so I have access to both. I am aware that only the `age` public key is required to encrypt, but the secret key is required in order to decrypt.

Now here's my question: if I want to add a key/value pair (or update an existing value) in an existing SOPS file that already contains encrypted values, do I need the ability to decrypt the file first? I know that I could create a brand new file and just encrypt that, but that seems messy, especially in a collaborative environment.

In short: is it possible to *add* a new value to a YAML file that has been encrypted with SOPS with only the public key available (i.e. without decrypting)?

---

For context, a bit of background info on my use-case: this project uses Terraform to manage infrastructure, and secrets are kept in a SOPS-encrypted file located in the terraform project directory (for those interested, I'm using [this provider](https://github.com/carlpett/terraform-provider-sops) to do stuff with the secret values). Our CI environment runs terraform, and has access to the `age` private key so that Terraform can (e.g.) set the password on database resources, etc. I want to make it so that developers can add new secrets, but cannot decrypt the secrets once they have been added.

Comment: I haven't used SOPS specifically and it might have some sort of special feature that changes the answer, but the general answer is no: most encryption schemes disallow this kind of behavior as it leads to specific forms of attack weakness.

Comment: @torek Interesting! Would you mind sharing any links or examples for learning more about that? Since SOPS-encrypted files keep their structure transparent (e.g. for YAML files, only the values are encrypted) I figured this wouldn't be much different than having something like a directory where each file (the key) is an independently-encrypted secret (the value), which doesn't seem like it would be considered a vulnerability.

Comment: Aha: if SOPS keeps the *keys* unencrypted, it's definitely designed with a weaker security model. (Note that just knowing what keys go with key-value pairs is a form of information leakage, which is why a more general crypto system wouldn't do that.) That weaker model *could* allow for this kind of update. Whether it does, well, that depends on the SOPS system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sops --set '["foo"]["bar"] "test"' ./test.enc.yaml to set or update just the foo.bar value without decrypting or altering the other entries.
This means that with PGP you can use the public key to set a new value without having access to the private values